# fetching data using access token

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I want to fetch feed/post/statuses data for a particular user.
But found that it is necessary to have an access token.
My concern is , do we need to have a separate access token for every user to fetch their information or merely with a single access token it is possible?

Comment: As I know an access token is seperate for each and every login. You can use the same access token for next use. But this access token has a expiry.

Comment: are you thinking about a specific (existing) service? Or are you developing your own service?

Comment: Apparently this is a Facebook API question. adding a tag.

Answer (score 3):

The access token is used to verify that the user making the call is verified and has the correct permissions to perform that action.  Every user has his/her own access token for each application.  As the comments say above, access tokens expire after a while, so you have to re-request them when the user logs back into your application.
There is also "long-term" access tokens that can be retrieved by requesting the `offline_access` permission.  In this case the access token is valid for (i think) 30 days or until the user changes his/her facebook password.
All the information you need about access tokens can be found at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

An Facebook Graph API access token allows you to do what a Facebook application running as a particular user, with a particular set of permissions (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/), is permitted to do. Some data on other Facebook objects (such as users) may be available with the access token of another user, especially if they are a "friend" of the user in the access token.

For example, suppose the access token specifies User A and permission "friends_birthday". You should be able to query the birthday of user B if (1) user B is a friend of user A, and (2) user B permits his/her friends to see his/her birthday.

I don't know your full scenario, but if you are really just fetching data, you may find it easier to use https://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com rather than writing your own Facebook application.